# Output custom function result in php template with UMI CMS

Tags: php, templates

I made my custom function in modules/custom.php file, and I'm trying to output its result into php template.

```
public function pagetemp($template = 'default') {
    list($template_block) = emarket::loadTemplates('emarket/' . $template, 'personal_link');
    $block_arr = [];
    return emarket::parseTemplate($template_block, $block_arr);
}
```

But it doesn't works.
How do I pass result of my custom function into php template? Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use method

```
macros($module, $method) : mixed
```

like this http://dev.docs.umi-cms.ru/spravochnik_makrosov_umicms/blogi/blogs20_commentslist/#php-templating (without $this->render)

Documentation: http://dev.docs.umi-cms.ru/shablony_i_makrosy/php-shablonizator_umi_cms/opisanie_api_php-shablonizatora/